# ¿Como mostrar cuantos caracteres tiene una variable en donde se almacenan números introducidos por teclado?

Tags: python-3.x

Quiero que cuando el usuario digite un numero de teléfono por teclado este se guarde en esta variable (number)

```
number = input(int("digite un numero teléfono :"))
```

y luego devuelva si esos números que se almacenan en la variable tienen mas de 9 caracteres.lo hice de esta forma pero no pude.

```
if number.len > 9:
  print("introduciste mas de 9 numeros")
```

Comment: El título de la pregunta no parece corresponder a la descripción del problema que das. ¿Qué tipo de datos estás usando?¿Dónde lees la variables `number` y la conviertes en `int`?¿Tienes problemas para obtener la longitud de una _string_? Deberías completar el código con lo que realmente estás probando.

Comment: ya lo edite. espero sea mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, dentro del input solo debes colocar el mensaje que quieres que se muestre al usuario, eso que quieres hacer se haria de esta manera

number = int(input("Digite un numero teléfono :"))

Pero eso causaria un error si el usuario ingresa letras, por ahora te diré mi solución propuesta que no incluye ese método.

```
number = input("Digite un numero teléfono :")

while not number.isdigit() or len(number) > 9:
    number = input("Digite un numero de teléfono válido:")

print(number)
```

Se pide al usuario que ingrese el número de teléfono.

Primero, [isdigit()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isdigit.asp) evalua un string y si este es netamente numeros, devuelve un valor booleano `True`, si no devuelve `False`, si por ejemplo evaluamos lo siguiete:

```
foo = "Hola123"
print(foo.isdigit())
```

Eso devolverá `False` porque la variable `foo` no contiene solo números, y al haber combinacion de numeros y letras este se convierte en un `string`.

Bien, entonces en el ciclo `while`, cuanto anteponemos `not` a la evaluación de la variable `number` en palabras sencillas estamos diciendo:

Mientras la evaluación de `number.isdigit()` NO devuelva `True` ejecutará lo que está dentro del `while`, recuerda que un ciclo `while` se ejecutará hasta que una de sus condiciones (o la unica que posea) sea falsa, o sea `False`. Entonces, al ingresar un `string` en nuestro script, `number.isdigit()` devuelve `False`, y como digimos antes, mientras  `number.isdigit()` no (`not`) devuelva `True` ejecutaremos el contenido del ciclo `while`. Ahora, la segunda condición es más facil, si la longitud del valor ingresado es mayor que 9, seguiremos ejecutando el `while`.

Entonces, como digimos, mientras el ciclo `while` siga obteniendo valores True, se seguirá ejecutando, pongamoslo así:

Si la variable `number` es igual a:

- **"Hola"** = Se seguirá pidiendo un número valido, porque no son numeros
- **"123"** = Finalizará el script, porque no hay letras y la lungitud es
  menor que 9.
- **"1234567890"** = Se seguirá pidiendo un número valido,
  porque excede el limite puesto.

Con ese ciclo `while` se matan 2 pajaros de un tiro, se evalua si lo ingresado es un numero y su longitud, solo debes comprender bien como funciona un ciclo [while](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp) para entender bien lo que sucede.